# Update field using foreach loop in codeigniter not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an issue I´m trying to update a field from a column using codeigniter , I display results from database using a foreach loop then I want to add a button called "reactivate" to change the status of that column, the PROBLEM is that it updates all the fields I just want to update the row I´m clicking in but it changes the 'Status' of all the other accounts, I don´t know how to solve this issue. Thanks in advance. 
This is my view:

```
div class='container'>
      <h5>Histórico</h5>
    <table id='table' class='table'>
     <thead>
      <tr>       
        <th>INTERNO</th>
        <th>CLABE</th>
        <th>FECHA_ALTA</th>
        <th>FECHA_BAJA</th>
        <th>STATUS</th>
        <th>ACCIÓN</th>
     </thead>
      <tbody>
<?php
        foreach ($mos-> result() as $row) {
          echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$row->Interno;"</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row->Clabe;"</td>";
                  echo "<td>".$row->Fecha_alta;"</td>";
                  echo "<td>".$row->Fecha_baja;"</td>";
                  echo "<td>".$row->Status;"</td>"; 
                echo "<td><input type='submit' id='ReActivar' name='ReActivar' class='btn btn-success' value='ReActivar' onclick='return validacion();' disabled><span id='msg'></span></td>";
         "</tr>";  
         }
      ?>    
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

This is my controller:

```
function decision(){
      if (!empty($_POST['actualizar'])) {
     $this->validaclabe();
      }

    if (!empty($_POST['Desactivar'])) {
   $this->update_Status();
}

if (!empty($_POST['ReActivar'])) {
   $this->update_Status_again();
}
}

function update_Status_again() 
{
     $this->load->helper('date'); 
      date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City'); 
      $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');    
    $Interno = $this->input->post('Interno');
    $Status = $this->input->post('activo');

     $data = array(
     'Status' =>  ! empty($Status) ? $Status : 'A',
    'Fecha_alta' => $now,
  );

    //$data['status'] = ! empty($Status) ? $Status : 'I';
    if ( ! empty($Interno))
    {
        $updated = $this->consultas_M->update_Status($Interno, $data);
        if($updated)
        {
           //echo " update successful...";
           $this->logueado();
           //redirect('index.php/Datos/search2');
        }
        else
        { echo "update not successful...";}  
    } else
    { echo "Interno  not found ..."; }    
}
```

This is the model:

```
function muestra_inactivos($Interno)
     {  $Status = 'A';
        //$Interno = $this->input->get('Interno');
        $this->db->select('Interno, Clabe, Fecha_alta, Fecha_baja, Status');
        $this->db->where('Status !=', $Status);
        $this->db->where('Interno =', $Interno);
    $q= $this->db ->get('cuentas');
  if($q -> num_rows() >= 0){
    return $q;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
  }

 function update_Status_again($Interno,$data)
{
   $this->db->where('Interno', $Interno);
   return $this->db->update('cuentas', $data);
   if ( $this->db->affected_rows() > 0 )
   {
      return TRUE;
   }
   else 
   {
     return FALSE;
   }

}
```

This is also a picture I also don´t know why one button is disabled and the other is not.[image: webpage]

Comment: Do you know how to do an ajax call?

Comment: Nop, I´m just using and able to use php, javascript, mysql and codeigniter syntax

Comment: Why is the value of your Interno 1 for both of records. It seems that your update query is using the Intero value to distinguish between records and update, but since it is same it's updating all the records. Are you sure you have made Interno value in mysql primary and set it to auto increment?

Comment: where is your validacation function?  Also, maybe you can put your - input type submit - in another loop of your foreach loop with different id's and see if it solves your issue

Comment: I second what Deepak says... if you are using interno to distinguish between them then the update will apply to all rows where `interno = 1` e.g. all the records. You should always have a unique column - use that.

Comment: The problem is that I have a combined primary key, so the primary key is "Interno + Clabe", interno represents the employee ID and Clabe is the bank transfer number, so I was told that one employee can have many transfer numbers but only one CLABE should be ACTIVE and the others inactive